# php - Não faz update em campo boolean

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Estou tentando fazer update dos dados do usuário, porém o campo ativo não é atualizado.

Já tentei diversas alterações e também mudar o valor da variável `$active` de `boolean` para `int`, mas sem sucesso.

Outro comportamento que notei é quando não faço nenhuma alteração nos campos e mando executar o update, o `$stmt->affected_rows` retorna 0, isso é normal?

```
public function user_update($user_id, $name, $email, $active)
{
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET user_name = ?, user_email = ?, user_active = ? WHERE user_id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ssbi", $name, $email, $active, $user_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $num_affected_rows = $stmt->affected_rows;
    $stmt->close();
    return $num_affected_rows > 0;
}
```

A versão do `php` é a 5.6.22, e a base é `MySQL`

Comment: o que vem em echo $active?

Comment: Olá, faz o seguinte tenta fazer uma condição, as vezes o booleano pega T ou F, ou em alguns casos pega 0 ou 1 , melhor inserir no banco manual e ver oque salva lá

Comment: @AndréBaill  vem true ou false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`b` é para campos/valores do tipo blob e não boolean, troque o `b` por `i` caso esteja passando 0 ou 1. Ou mude para `s` para valores `t` ou `f`

```
$stmt->bind_param("ssii", $name, $email, $active, $user_id);
```

Comment: Já mudei para i e não deu certo, vou tentar colocar s

Comment: @adelmo00 pega o retorno do erro com, `$stmt->execute() or die(mysqli_error($this->conn));`

Comment: mudei  para s e deu certo